# How to remove a specific result within an list of results within an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which is grabbing results from my database, and then passing some results to a mapbox geocoder. However i want to put some error catching in it so when the geocoder returns a null/undefined value for the address, it'll remove not only that undefined value but everything else attached to that result.

I'm trying to remove a specific element using the .splice method, whilst it's detecting that a undefined value exists, it'll then remove the whole addresses result from the array rather than just the one address and all the other results. (I'm assuming that say if address 3 is undefined, you can remove everything in the array that is at position 3 since that'll be the results that are attached to that address value),

So as described below

```
       let projects = values.map(elmt => elmt[5])
```

Is the bit i want to check for any undefined or null valyes coming back from the geocoder.

funciton

```
  function grabProjects() {
    sql = 'SELECT o.Name, o.Project_Type, o.sDate, o.eDate, p.Role, p.Project_Org_Address, p.Project_Org_Name,p.Country_Name, p.Country_Name, f.Funder_Name, per.Person_Name FROM project_name_table o INNER JOIN project_collaborators p ON o.Project_ID = p.Project_ID INNER JOIN project_funders f ON f.Project_ID = o.Project_ID INNER JOIN person per ON o.person_fk = per.Person_ID GROUP BY o.Project_ID LIMIT 20'
  projectsArray = []

    let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;



      const geoPromise = param => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        geo.geocode('mapbox.places', param, function (err, geoData) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          if (geoData) {
            resolve(geoData.features[0])
          } else {
            reject('No result found');
          }
        });
      });



      const promises = results.map(result =>

        Promise.all([
          result.Name,
          result.Project_Type,
          result.sDate,
          result.eDate,
          result.Role,
          geoPromise(result.Project_Org_Address),
          result.Project_Org_Name,
          geoPromise(result.Country_Name),
          result.Country_Name,
          result.Funder_Name,
          result.Person_Name

        ])

      );

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then((values) => {

          let pNames = values.map(elmt => elmt[0])
          let pType = values.map(elmt => elmt[1])
          let sDate = values.map(elmt => elmt[2])
          let eDate = values.map(elmt => elmt[3])
          let roles = values.map(elmt => elmt[4])
          let projects = values.map(elmt => elmt[5])
          let collabNames = values.map(elmt => elmt[6])
          let countryNames = values.map(elmt => elmt[7])
          let countryProjects = values.map(elmt => elmt[8])
          let names = values.map(elmt => elmt[9])
          let person_name = values.map(elmt => elmt[10])

          projectsArray.push(pNames, pType, sDate, eDate, roles, projects, collabNames, countryNames, countryProjects, names, person_name)
          console.log(projectsArray.length)

          for (i = 0; i < projectsArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(projectsArray[5][i])
            if (projectsArray[5][i] === undefined) {
              console.log('true')
              projectsArray.splice(i, 1)
              console.log('new length', projectsArray.length)


            }
            else {
              console.log('false')
            }
          }
        })


    });





    return projectsArray



  }
```

Comment: How about `Array.filter()`?

Comment: How can i get that to delete a whole row of elements?

Comment: I think you'd be better off not adding the row in the first place.

Comment: so catching it in the promise.all(values) or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can be refactored better to achieve what you want to do. As noted in my comment you'd be better off not adding the new row unless it passes your test. Something along the lines of:

```
function grabProjects() {
    // ...
    projectsArray = []

    let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      ...//
      results.forEach(async (result) => {
           const parsedResult = result
           const address = await geoPromise(result.Project_Org_Address;
           const country = await geoPromise(result.Country_Name);
           result.address = address;
           result.country = country;

           const propUndefined = Object.keys(result).filter((key) => result[key] === undefined).length > 0;

           if (!propUndefined) {
               projectsArray.push(Object.keys(result).map((key) => result[key]);
           }

        //...

    return projectsArray;
});
```